# What is a State Tree in React JS

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux

I am new to ReactJS and  finished parts of my ReactJS courses that I was taking until I came across Redux where it was talking about uses of Single State tree. I want to know what a state tree actually means

Comment: https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles a state tree isn't anything special, it's literally just the state object. A 'single state tree' refers to the fact that in Redux, you have *ONE* state tree (object) which everything connects to. A _single_ state object that acts as the universal source of truth for your application's state.

Comment: thank you @Jayce444

Answer (score 1):

I agree @A.M Usmani

A state tree isn't anything special, it's literally just the state object. A 'single state tree' refers to the fact that in Redux, you have ONE state tree (object) which everything connects to. A single state object that acts as the universal source of truth for your application's stateView

create visualization for the state of each component eg like below picture and

Categorize each reducer like below

const headerReducer = combineReducer({
menu: menuReducer,
search: searchReducer,
location: locationReducer
});

const rootReducer = combineReducer({
header: headerReducer,
login: loginReducer,
footer: footerReducer,
common: commonReducer,
product: productReducer,
catalog: catalogReducer,
payment: paymentReducer
});

[image: Visualise state tree]

Please go through this link you will get good understanding : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-best-way-to-architect-your-redux-app-ad9bd16c8e2d/